# Python: Importing a module with the same name as a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

For background: First time asking a question on SE. I'm still quite new at Python, and not very experienced with programming in general. I've searched around but I haven't found an answer to this question, and I'd greatly appreciate your help.

My question is: How can I import a module which has the same name as a function?

To be specific, I am working with the Python symbolic math library, sympy 0.7.5, using Python 2.7.

Sympy has a structure like this:

```
sympy
 |
 +-- __init__.py
 +-- simplify
       |
       +-- __init__.py
       +-- simplify.py
       |      |       
       |      +-- def simplify(...)
       |
       +-- fu.py
            |
            +-- def TR8(...)
            +-- def fu(...)
```

What I am looking to do is import fu.py from this structure, so that I can call the TR8 function. However, I'm not having much luck.

This works:

```
from sympy.simplify.fu import *

TR8(some_expression)
```

So far, this is the only way I am able to access TR8, but I know it's not the recommended way.

The following attempts fail:

```
from sympy.simplify import fu

fu.TR8(some_expression)
>>AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'TR8'

from sympy import fu

fu.TR8(some_expression)
>>AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'TR8'
```

I'm not certain, but it seems to me like Python thinks I'm trying to import the function called fu instead of the module called fu. Likewise, When I try it this way:

```
import sympy.simplify.fu as fu
>>AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fu'
```

Here Python seems to think I'm talking about the function sympy.simplify.simplify, instead of the module sympy.simplify.

So is there a proper way to ask Python to import a module, when that module contains a function with the same name as the module?

Comment: Can't you just `from sympy.simplify.fu import TR8`?

Comment: You should not be able to do `from sympy import fu` at all! Are you sure your code is exactly the way you depicted? Do you have any stale .pyc file?

Comment: Can you copy-paste an actual interpreter session into your question to show us the failure? You appear to have retyped it instead of copy-pasting, which is a highly unreliable way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`sympy/simplify/__init__.py`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/simplify/__init__.py) contains the following line:

```
from .fu import FU, fu
```

This hides the `fu` module by assigning the `fu` function where you would expect the module to go, blocking most ways to import it.

If you just want the TR8 function, you can import that:

```
from sympy.simplify.fu import TR8
```

If you need the `fu` module, an entry remains in `sys.modules`:

```
import sympy.simplify.fu
import sys

fu_module = sys.modules['sympy.simplify.fu']
```

It's ugly, but it should work. As far as I know, this is the simplest way to get at the module itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a namespace for the module.

```
from simpy.simplify import fu as fu_module
```

That should work just fine.

Comment: This doesn't work. Aside from the misspelling of "sympy" ("simpy" is an unrelated module), with the spelling fixed, this imports the function, not the module.