# What is the right way to write a Python import statement

Tags: python, import, conventions

Please help understand what is the difference of these three import statements and what exactly happens under the hood when they get executed.

```
>>import lxml

>>import lxml.html

>>from lxml import html
```

I understand the first the first import will result in the whole lxml module being in the available in the current scope.

The third import results in only the html submodule being available in the scope.

So what is the end effect of the middle / second import? and if it has a similar effect to
any of the other two then which one is the most Pythonic way and why to do you two ways to achieve the same effect?

Thanks

Comment: The questions has down votes, why? Am I asking the obvious? it's not so obvious to me..

Answer (score 5):

#### Difference 1

1. When using `import lxml.html`, you need to use `lxml.html` to
   reference the module you imported.
2. When using `from lxml import html`, you can use `html` to reference
   it.

#### Difference 2

If there is another `html` module, you have imported, using `from lxml import html` may cause an conflict, but `import lxml.html` will not, since there is a *namespace* `lxml` before it.

#### Difference 3

You can use `from xx import v` to import object `v` from module `xx`, but you can not do this with `import xx.v`.

Comment: Note that if `__init__.py` file inside `lxml` contains a variable named `html` then the last import is going to import that not the module `html`.

Comment: Note also that ``import lxml`` is effectively the same as ``import lxml.html`` in this case and both bring in ``lxml`` into ``sys.modules`` and the current scope.

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction: Having such a variable in `__init__.py` would be a bad idea, though, since if anyone does `import lxml.html`, that overwrites the variable. I've seen a case where [the resulting interactions in the import system get really weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374155/python-importing-a-module-with-the-same-name-as-a-function).

Comment: so why do `import lxml.html` while you can just do `import lxml` and access html via `lxml.html`

Comment: @JamesMills: Both `import lxml` and `import lxml.html` load the `lxml` package, but only `import lxml.html` loads the `lxml.html` module. The forms would only be equivalent if `lxml`'s `__init__.py` specifically loaded the `lxml.html` module; importing a package does not automatically import its submodules.

Comment: @misspec: You can't. `import lxml` won't load `lxml.html`.

Comment: @user2357112 In this specific case the difference is negligible.

Comment: @JamesMills: Not if we want the `html` module, which appears to be the entire point of the import.

Comment: @user2357112 I said access. Try this: `import lxml` then `h = lxml.html` You can access `html` that way

Comment: @misspec: Did that actually work? In a fresh interpreter session, after executing `import lxml` and nothing else, did accessing `lxml.html` not raise an `AttributeError`? If so, that must be a version difference, because it throws an error when I try it.

Comment: @user2357112 I get an `AttributeError` too.

Comment: Guys I just need to understand the purpose of `import lxml.html` and when to use it instead of `import lxml` and accessing the html or just  loading `html` alone via `from lxml import html`

Comment: sorry guys yeah `AttributeError' I had made previous imports on my session. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2357112 I believe your response to JamesMills is the correct answer. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @misspec For me, when I only need `html` and there is not conflict, I will use `from lxml import html`. In this way, I don't have to use `lxml.html` to reference it. And I think there is no standard for how to choose one of `import lxml.html` and `from lxml import html`.